# How do I find all currently running setInterval in Nodejs?

Tags: node.js, setinterval

I am working on coding a game website, and the server has multiplayer rooms that each have intervals that send updates to the players and make the game run. My problem is after a few days of the server running, it uses a lot more CPU and memory than it should, in some cases going up to 100%. I think the intervals aren't being cleared and they are running in the background. Is there any way I can list all intervals or use another way to find out the cause of my problem?

And if its possible, can it be done in vanilla js so I can use it on other projects

Comment: IIRC there's nothing built in; the usual solution is to wrap/replace the default `setInterval` with something that stores the interval refs. The *first* thing I would do is verify that what you think is happening is actually happening, e.g., do some logging or something.